# Why mongodb only updates the first matching document in the collection?

Tags: mongodb

Consider a collection student contains the following documents.

```
{name:”Nithin”,age:23} 

{name:”Nithin”,age:25} 

{name:”Nithin”,age:28} 

{name:”Nithin”,age:12}
```

I want to update all the documents whose name is “Nithin” as age=60. 
If we execute the following query it will only update the first document.

```
db.student.update({name:”Nithin”},{age:60})
```

For update all the documents I have to use the query

```
db.student.update({name:”Nithin”},{age:60},false,true) 

or 

db.student.update({name:”Nithin”},{age:60},multi:true)
```

What is the reason by default mongodb not updating all the documents by executing **db.student.update({name:”Nithin”},{age:60})** ? What is the motivation for creating separate queries for updating all the documents? Is it improving the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, in the early early days of MongoDB (pre 1.1) it was not possible to update multiple documents. This was a feature added around 1.1.3.

You can see it in the [release notes](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=10080), [New Feature 268](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-268).

I'm guessing this was not enabled by default for backwards compatibility with previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

This may not really be the reason but I find the additional `multi` parameter as a safeguard to prevent accidental update of multiple records when one intends to update a single document only, something like accidentally performing `UPDATE...SET` on SQL without specifying additional constraints.

Again this is just an assumption but may not really be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose part of the reason might be to avoid people coming from the SQL world to think about multi-document updates as isolated transactions.

In fact, during a long update MongoDB will periodically yield control to other queries which can potentially modify the same dataset.

So, by explicitly setting `multi=true` you are somewhat acknowledging this fact (well, not really, but I guess that's the spirit...)